# How do I run Fortran 77 code on Mac?

Tags: terminal, compilation, fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to run a program written in Fortran 77 in the terminal on Mac. I've downloaded the gfortran compiler but I can't seem to get it to compile. When I put in:

```
cd /path/to/file
gfortran -o my_program my_program.f
```

I get the following error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've done some research and it looks like it can't compile because my program doesn't have a main function. Is there any way to bypass this? I don't want to mess with the code since I don't know Fortran.

When I run the file anyway, terminal doesn't recognize the language since it doesn't interpret comment syntax as comments.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How about some "hello world" example then, so everyone can view your code and your errors. If you do not have a main, then you may need a -c in the compile line. What are you expecting to link the code along with?

Answer (score 2):

Start with saving this as hello_world.for and trying to compiling it.

```
      PROGRAM Hello_World
      IMPLICIT NONE
!234567
      WRITE(*,*)'Hello World'
      END PROGRAM Hello_World
```

After that then we can move on.

I have a lot of code with no "main". Usually they end up in a library. On ifort it is '-c' for for compile only, probavly the same on gfort. Then one can link the .o files with a program.

It will be somthing like

```
 gfort -c -o somename.o samename.for
```

Comment: upvote just to offset an inexplicable downvote.

Comment: This does not answer anything. You can ask in the comments (and link any hello world on SO or elsewhere).

Comment: I think the comment contained the answer, specifically in terms of a "compile but do not link" switch... I suppose that he/she could link their existing code with the hello world.